# MySQL replication as both master and slave (replication loop?)

Tags: mysql, sql, replication

I've got two MySQL servers, one as a master in the replication process and the other as the slave. I was wondering if anything bad would happen if I made the current master a slave to the current slave, and the current slave a master to the current master. So basically, both servers would be replicating to and from each other.

I saw some questions and posts on other sites about 'replication loops', which is how I would describe my question; but these posts seemed to be explaining something completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is a master master MySQL setup. It is well documented and supported. We've been using it for many years and we were not early adopters.

The set ups that I've worked on have used the master/master active/passive setup, meaning that only one side takes writes at any given time. We setup a floating IP between the two to manage the write master.

Comment: I actually [asked this question on dba.stackexchange once I found out about it](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44425/mysql-replication-as-both-master-and-slave-replication-loop) - The answer I got there goes into good detail on the subject.